# Inserting Image in Python in Visual Studio

Tags: python, image

I use Visual Studio (not Visual Studio Code) to write Python code. I searched a lot, but cant find an information how to insert an image from my computer (.png, .jpeg and etc). I also need to edit this picture using different functions.

How can I set up all.of this things for Python on Visual Studio?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You type the path to the image.

Answer (score 2):

You do not insert the image into Visual Studio, your python code needs to open it from the computer. For modifying images I would recommend [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Open the image in your script by calling `Image.open(PATH_TO_IMAGE)`, and then you can modify it and save it. Here's an example of opening the image `image.png` from the script folder, converting it to grayscale, and then saving as `grayscale.png`

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image.png').convert('LA')
img.save('greyscale.png')
```

For more info about paths in python and how it all works check out [Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 8 (Paths)](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter8/).